# mysql: Populate data in a column from different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to populate data in a column from different columns based on some criteria for example, I have a table:

```
MyTable( id, area_id, name )
```

with sample data:

```
10 1 <name>
20 2 <name>
30 3 <name>
40 4 <name>
50 1 <name>
60 2 <name>
70 3 <name>
80 4 <name>
```

Now I want this table to be updated as

```
10 1 Area 1
20 2 Area 2
30 3 Area 3
40 4 Area 4
50 1 Area 1
60 2 Area 2
70 3 Area 3
80 4 Area 4
```

How to achieve this in a single query.

Comment: Do you want to add a new column or just update the existing column name with Area 1 or Area 2 like the examples?

Comment: Column is already there, I just want to update it, But It'll be great if someone can also provide query which also can create a new column. :)

Comment: `+1` for adding sample records with desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since column `name` already exist, do update with the use of `CONCAT`

```
UPDATE tableName
SET name = CONCAT('Area ', area_id)
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ada2f/1)

If you want to add another column, please read the article

- [**Add a column to an existing MySQL table**](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/378/add-a-column-to-an-existing-mysql-table/)

Answer (score 3):

**[SQLFIDDLEexample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df31a/1)**
Update your table :

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET `name` = CONCAT('Area ', area_id);
```

Insert new column and update it

```
ALTER TABLE `MyTable` ADD `new_name` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ;

UPDATE MyTable
SET `new_name` = CONCAT('Area ', area_id);
```

Result:

```
| ID | AREA_ID |   NAME | NEW_NAME |
------------------------------------
| 10 |       1 | Area 1 |   Area 1 |
| 20 |       2 | Area 2 |   Area 2 |
| 30 |       3 | Area 3 |   Area 3 |
| 40 |       4 | Area 4 |   Area 4 |
| 50 |       1 | Area 1 |   Area 1 |
| 60 |       2 | Area 2 |   Area 2 |
| 70 |       3 | Area 3 |   Area 3 |
| 80 |       4 | Area 4 |   Area 4 |
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a new column (as mentioned in the comments) :

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD areaName VARCHAR(60);
```

To update the existing table with new values in the column `name`:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET name = CONCAT('Area ', area_id)
```